# Conexão remota do SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, conexão

Tenho 2 servidores (um físico e uma VM local) na qual um deles tem o SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition (físico) instalado e o outro (VM local) tenho o SQL Server 2008 Express Edition.

Depois de enfrentar problemas com a conexão remota na versão Express, descobri que eu deveria habilitar e rodar o serviço "Navegador do SQL Server" além das outras configurações de firewall, TCP/IP.

Minha questão é a seguinte:
Para acessar remotamente o servidor com a versão Enterprise eu não preciso estar rodando o serviço de navegação do SQL Server, já a versão Express eu preciso deixar ele rodando.
Alguém saberia dizer o porque isso ocorre?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> O Navegador do SQL Server escuta as solicitações de entrada dos
>   recursos do Microsoft SQL Server e fornece informações sobre as
>   instâncias instaladas do SQL Server no computador

A diferença entre as instalações Express das convencionais é que por padrão o SQL Express utiliza uma instância nomeada `SQLEXPRESS`. Já as outras edições utilizam o nome da instância padrão `MSSQLSERVER`, instância essa que pode ser omitida ao acessar remotamente o servidor.

Pela instância física não ser nomeada e estar habilitada na porta padrão (1433), após a liberação do Firewall e do TCP/IP, ela já esteja pronta para o uso e não precisa do serviço do `Navegador do SQL Server` habilitado.

De acordo com essa pergunta do [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18457/why-does-sql-browser-service-get-disabled), esse serviço é desabilitado por padrão por causa de uma [ameaça de negação de serviço](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_DoS) chamada [SQL Slammer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Slammer).